# Extruded Polymer build up on extrusion tooling (Cone/Tip)

Tags: polymer

We re currently trying to manufacture a single lumen product made from HDPE with turquoise colourant. Due to the polymer (drying not required) and the tube specifications, we are using a vacuum tank to form the extruded tube. We have no issue with making the tube dimensionally, the issue is with HDPE building up on the cone/tip and breaking off. The material we are using is:

```
Material: Ineos B54-25H-127 HDPE + 0.1% PCC turquoise FDA PE CPE2541 (compounded)
Processing temps:  Barrel Zones (275-330⁰F), adaptors (380-445⁰F), Cross Head (450⁰F)
OD = 1.092mm
ID = 0.406mm
Cone/Tip: 0.64 (mandrel)
Die Size: 1.85
DDR: 2.94
DDB: 1.08
```

The Inner Diameter is checked with a mandrel but sometimes the ID is blocking from

1. Material build up on the cone and breaking off
2. Some Ovality issues.

We have polished the tip (polished mandrel) and also created a very small radius on the outside of the tip to reduce material build up.

1. Can you suggest a possible solution to reduce/eliminate polymer buildup and
2. Line speed is 4.5 metres/min (very slow due to vacuum) – ways to increase line speed?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Pretty sure this is on the [wrong StackExchange site](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Maybe http://physics.stackexchange.com/ ?